# Do you have to format the printout from print_r() in PHP to have it validate with W3C?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, printing

This will not validate because of the output from print_r, is it not supposed to be used "on a site" or do one have to format it in a certain way?

```
  <?php
   $stuff1 = $_POST["stuff1"];//catch variables
   $stuff2 = $_POST["stuff2"]; 
   $stuff3 = $_POST["stuff3"]; 
   $myStuff[0] = $stuff1;//put into array
   $myStuff[1] = $stuff2;
   $myStuff[2] = $stuff3;

   print_r($myStuff);

  ?>
```

Comment: You mean the PHP generates HTML which will not validate? What does the Validator say is the problem?

Comment: It says:Error  Line 19, Column 99: character data is not allowed here

…> </p><h4>Printout with print_r:</h4>Array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print_r()` is mainly designed as a helpful tool for developers, not for actual production use in a manner that end-users would see. Thus, you shouldn't really be trying to validate it - if you're at the stage where you're trying to get stuff to validate, you shouldn't be using `print_r` anyway.

Comment: Ok it is just a tool in the development process?

Answer (score 5):

The validator can't distinguish the output of print_\r() from the surrounding html structure; it simply parses the whole character stream. If the output of your print_r() contains characters that have a special meaning in html (apparently < and > in your case) the validator must assume that it belongs to the html structure, not the text data. You have to mark them as "no, this is just text data, not a control character" for html parsers. One way to do this is to send [entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) instead of the "real" character itself, e.g. &lt; instead of <
The function [htmlspecialchars()](http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars) takes care of those characters that always have a special meaning in (x)html.
You might also want to enclose the output in a [<pre>....</pre> element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-PRE) to keep the formatting of print_r().

```
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(print_r($myStuff, true)), "</pre>\n";
```

Comment: Finally! It took 5 answers before someone mentioned htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 1):

A plain `print_r` outputs text, so there's no reason for it not to affect validation. To print it out nicely formatted on an HTML page, use a `<pre>`:

```
$printout = print_r($my_var);
echo "<pre>$printout</pre>";
```

If you don't want to display it, but only to see it as a developer, place it in an HTML (`<!-- any text -->`).

Comment: Plain text may not appear in every HTML element, so it *can* affect validation. Judging by the comment below the question, this is the OPs problem.